# Data is not a numeric-literal (IES 10901) (WIS 10901)

Tags: business-objects

Seems like another in a row of BusinessObject bugs. Here is the background: Set of objects was selected and a filter was set on those objects. Now, when I run that query in Information Design Tool, I GET exactly the rows I am expecting. Then I publish the universe, and run the same query with WEBI, and then I get this message:

```
"Data is not a numeric-literal (IES 10901) (WIS 10901)"
```

Please somebody give me a reasonable "BO-Style" explanation why the same query works in IDT and is not working in WEBI.

Generated SQL statement:

```
SELECT
  D_ATA_MV_FinanceTreasury.VWD_Party_A.Party_KEY,
  D_ATA_MV_FinanceTreasury.VWD_Party_A.Location_KEY,
  D_ATA_MV_FinanceTreasury.VWD_Party_A.Name_NAM,
  D_ATA_MV_FinanceTreasury.VWD_Party_A.Given_Name_NAM,
  D_ATA_MV_FinanceTreasury.VWD_Party_A.Short_Name_NAM,
  D_ATA_MV_FinanceTreasury.VWD_Party_A.Date_Of_Birth_DAT,
  D_ATA_MV_FinanceTreasury.VWD_Nationality_A.Nation_German_NAM,
  D_ATA_MV_FinanceTreasury.VWD_Segment_Value_A.Description_TXT,
  D_ATA_MV_FinanceTreasury.VWD_Party_A.Company_Reg_Number_TXT,
  D_ATA_MV_FinanceTreasury.VWD_Party_A.Vat_Code_TXT,
  D_ATA_MV_FinanceTreasury.VWD_Party_A.Employees_NUM,
  D_ATA_MV_FinanceTreasury.VWD_Party_A.Customer_From_DAT,
  D_ATA_MV_FinanceTreasury.VWD_Party_A.Last_Edit_DAT,
  D_ATA_MV_FinanceTreasury.VWD_Party_A.ANZ_BEN_pro_Party,
  sum(D_ATA_MV_FinanceTreasury.VWF_Party_Umsatz_A.Umsatz_Gesamt)
FROM
  D_ATA_MV_FinanceTreasury.VWD_Nationality_A RIGHT OUTER JOIN D_ATA_MV_FinanceTreasury.VWD_Party_A ON (D_ATA_MV_FinanceTreasury.VWD_Nationality_A.Nation_CD=D_ATA_MV_FinanceTreasury.VWD_Party_A.Nationality_CD)
   LEFT OUTER JOIN D_ATA_MV_FinanceTreasury.VWD_Segment_Value_A ON (D_ATA_MV_FinanceTreasury.VWD_Segment_Value_A.Segment_Value_KEY=D_ATA_MV_FinanceTreasury.VWD_Party_A.Segment_Value_KEY)
   INNER JOIN D_ATA_MV_FinanceTreasury.VWF_Party_Umsatz_A ON (D_ATA_MV_FinanceTreasury.VWD_Party_A.Party_KEY=D_ATA_MV_FinanceTreasury.VWF_Party_Umsatz_A.Party_KEY)

GROUP BY
  1, 
  2, 
  3, 
  4, 
  5, 
  6, 
  7, 
  8, 
  9, 
  10, 
  11, 
  12, 
  13, 
  14
```

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the data provider and add both generated SQL statements?

Comment: I edited the post by adding the generated SQL statement. Please take a look at it. Moreover, this statement functions without any problems when I run it with Teradata Assistant.
In regard to data provider I am not sure what you think. Do you mean screenshot of the connection? If yes, there are not much information to show...

Comment: UPDATE: It looks as if the problem is with 'Segment Value' (when I eliminate this attribute from the query panel, then I get a result set). But why? What is the cause?

Comment: 'Data Type' is set on 'Numeric'. I'll change it to 'String'. That should work. I'll keep you up-to-date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the *Error Messages Explained* guide, it states:

> Database error: {error_db}. (IES 10901)
>
> Cause: The database returned the error given in the message.

In other words, the SQL statement that was generated and sent to the database resulted in a database error. One possible explanation could be that there is a implicit conversion (i.e. from alphanumeric to numeric) which is causing the error message.

As for the difference in IDT and Webi running the same query: keep in mind that IDT will (by default) only retrieve the first 200 rows, not the complete dataset. If the issue was caused by an implicit conversion, this would mean that the offending record was not a part of that sample set retrieved by IDT, thus not resulting in an error.

Comment: After changing 'Data Type' from 'Numeric' to 'String' it works as expected. By the way, I clicked on 'Generate' buton not only in IDT but also in WEBI. I suppose in both cases only a subset of the whole data are retrieved. Anyway, I appreciate your feedback. It's always good to hear what you think about the BO issues.